# Why does this for loop not cycle through the list?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a loop to create a deck of cards. I understand this isn't an efficient way of doing this, but I want to try anyways. For some reason the for loop doesn't cycle through the "Suits" list like it should. Any ideas why?

```
#Pre Assigned Variables
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
cards = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack"]
deck = []
counter = 0 

#Loop to create deck list
for i in suits:
    while counter != 13:
        card = str(cards[counter]), "of", str(i)
        deck.append(card)
        counter += 1
```

When I print the deck list, here is what comes up:

```
[('Two', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Three', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Four', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Five', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Six', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Seven', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Eight', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Nine', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Ten', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Ace', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('King', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Queen', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Jack', 'of', 'Hearts')]
```

Comment: You don't reset `counter`. Move `counter = 0` to hust before the `while` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when your counter reaches 13 in the first loop of 'Hearts', it never resets and that's why it doesn't cycle through the other suits.
So instead of using the counter, you can use another loop to iterate through the cards.

```
for i in suits:
    for j in cards:
        card = j, "of", i
        deck.append(card)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset your `counter` variable before each loop.
Try this:

```py
#Pre Assigned Variables
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
cards = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack"]
deck = []


#Loop to create deck list
for i in suits:
    counter = 0
    while counter != 13:
        card = str(cards[counter]), "of", str(i)
        deck.append(card)
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [`itertools.product`](http://[('Two',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Three',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Four',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Five',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Six',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Seven',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Eight',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Nine',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Ten',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Ace',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('King',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Queen',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Jack',%20'of',%20'Hearts'),%20('Two',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Three',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Four',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Five',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Six',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Seven',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Eight',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Nine',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Ten',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Ace',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('King',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Queen',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Jack',%20'of',%20'Diamonds'),%20('Two',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Three',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Four',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Five',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Six',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Seven',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Eight',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Nine',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Ten',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Ace',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('King',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Queen',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Jack',%20'of',%20'Clubs'),%20('Two',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Three',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Four',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Five',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Six',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Seven',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Eight',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Nine',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Ten',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Ace',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('King',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Queen',%20'of',%20'Spades'),%20('Jack',%20'of',%20'Spades')]) for this.

```
import itertools as it
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
cards = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack"]
deck = []
#Loop to create deck list
for suit,card in it.product(suits,cards):
    deck.append((card,"of",suit))
print(deck)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('Two', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Three', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Four', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Five', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Six', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Seven', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Eight', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Nine', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Ten', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Ace', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('King', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Queen', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Jack', 'of', 'Hearts'), ('Two', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Three', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Four', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Five', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Six', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Seven', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Eight', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Nine', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Ten', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Ace', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('King', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Queen', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Jack', 'of', 'Diamonds'), ('Two', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Three', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Four', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Five', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Six', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Seven', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Eight', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Nine', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Ten', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Ace', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('King', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Queen', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Jack', 'of', 'Clubs'), ('Two', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Three', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Four', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Five', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Six', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Seven', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Eight', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Nine', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Ten', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Ace', 'of', 'Spades'), ('King', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Queen', 'of', 'Spades'), ('Jack', 'of', 'Spades')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want each index to have the full string (rather than tuple of strings) corresponding to the card and its suit.

**Adding to Xilin's answer, the full code will look like:**

```
#Pre Assigned Variables
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
cards = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack"]
deck = []

for i in suits:
    for j in cards:
        name = j + " of " + i # Note the space prior to and after the word 'of'
        deck.append(name)
```

**You might as well get used to formatting strings (quiet useful):**

```
for i in suits:
  for j in cards:
    name = "{card} of {suit}".format(card=j, suit=i) 
    deck.append(name)
```

OR simply:

```
for i in suits:
  for j in cards:
    name = "{} of {}".format(j, i) 
    deck.append(name)
```

More details about the formatting can be found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/

**This will produce the output:**

```
['Two of Hearts', 'Three of Hearts', 'Four of Hearts', 'Five of Hearts', 'Six of Hearts', 'Seven of Hearts', 'Eight of Hearts', 'Nine of Hearts', 'Ten of Hearts', 'Ace of Hearts', 'King of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Two of Diamonds', 'Three of Diamonds', 'Four of Diamonds', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Seven of Diamonds', 'Eight of Diamonds', 'Nine of Diamonds', 'Ten of Diamonds', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Two of Clubs', 'Three of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Five of Clubs', 'Six of Clubs', 'Seven of Clubs', 'Eight of Clubs', 'Nine of Clubs', 'Ten of Clubs', 'Ace of Clubs', 'King of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Two of Spades', 'Three of Spades', 'Four of Spades', 'Five of Spades', 'Six of Spades', 'Seven of Spades', 'Eight of Spades', 'Nine of Spades', 'Ten of Spades', 'Ace of Spades', 'King of Spades', 'Queen of Spades', 'Jack of Spades']
```

Which you can get by using: `print(deck)`